# How to properly constrain an SVG image inside a container?

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a circular colored **Container** in the middle of the screen with fixed square dimensions. As a child for this container there is an **SvgPicture**. By default the **SvgPicture** takes the dimensions of it's parent and this is not the intended behavior.

The goal is to make the container squish the SvgPicture such that the image is always smaller than its container.

I tried using a **Padding** around the **SvgPicture** but for some reason everything grows out of proportion using this approach.

```
class SplashIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashIcon({
    super.key,
    required this.imageSize,
    required this.imagePath,
  });

  final double imageSize;
  final String imagePath;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: imageSize,
      height: imageSize,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: AppColor.defaultStyle.primaryColor50,
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: SvgPicture.asset(imagePath),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @bqubique I just added the class which I am working with.

Answer (score 0):

You should use fit:BoxFit.cover properties for covering the entire container and preserving the aspect ratio.

SvgPicture.asset('assets/home.svg', fit:BoxFit.cover)

Comment: No BoxFit property is found in SvgPicture from flutter_svg (2.0.4).

Comment: in this case what version are you using

Comment: The property name is `fit`, not `BoxFit`.

Comment: @saberaoufi The version is 2.0.4.

Comment: @XUNITAccount just recheck property fit:BoxFit.cover , it exist in svg 2.0.4, write your code as mine it will work for you

Comment: @saberaoufi I just added the class which I am working with.

Comment: @XUNITAccount  I didn't get it, is my suggestion worked for you, or you have solved the problem by your self